# Alter page content using custom module

Tags: 7, theming

I'm writing a custom module which will process information using an external service and need to display any errors thrown by this service.

I already have a variable containing error messages.

How can I target a page body markup to show the error message? I have tried hook_page_alter but failed not knowing if a page body can be processed at this stage.

Thanks

Comment: It's harder to help when we don't know your Drupal version.

Comment: @NoSssweat Sorry. I'm using Drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Drupal message system.

Ex: `drupal_set_message(t('Error message goes in here'), 'error');`

In you case: `drupal_set_message(t($yourvariable), 'error');`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @NoSssweat However I'm targeting a different page. Therefore how can I call `drupal_set_message` in a specific page?

Comment: I have never done that before. I believe the message shows up on whatever page you visit next, so you could try redirecting the user with [drupal_goto()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x) ex: `drupal_goto("/node/1");`

Comment: Sure I will try using `drupal_set_message`. The reason I can't use `drupal_go_to` is that I'm redirecting user already using 'Webform Confirm Email' module. This module has a field to enter page that needs user redirected after he/she validates email address. So originally I'm looking at displaying the error message on this page.